# Only spellcheck HTML text

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is there a way to make the spelling inspection only check the actual text of an HTML page -- the visible text when you view the page in a browser?

I don't want to spellcheck any of the HTML code, just the actual text.

Turning off the 'Process Code' option in the Spelling > Typo Inspection turns off everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, please vote:

- [WI-13036](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13036) Spell-checker treats HTML text as code